# How to create a Menu at the top of a Frame which is not at the top of the window Python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, menu

Basically, I am creating a To - Do List which has a series of Notebook tabs on the side, when clicked, displaying a ScrolledText window on the right side. Here is a picture of the To - Do List. [Here is the image link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOogQ.png)
However, what I want is for there to be a Menu on top of the Scrolled Text. The main window, called root, is seperated using the Notebook Widget. When a tab is clicked, the area including the scrolled text is a seperate frame, called Task1, which I want the Menu bar to be on top of. Task1 does not reach the top of the window, it is the right section of the main window, not including the gray bar at the top. I want the Menu bar to be at the top of Task1, not at the top of the main window. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu, filedialog

root = Tk()

class ToDoList(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)


root.title("To - Do List")
root.geometry("1200x600")
root.configure(background = "white")
# Variable list:

style = ttk.Style()                     
current_theme =style.theme_use()
style.theme_settings(current_theme, {"TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [20, 5], "background" : "white"}}})
style.theme_settings(current_theme, {"TNotebook" : {"configure" : {"tabposition" : "wn", "padding" : (0, 5)}}})
style.theme_settings(current_theme, {"TNotebook.Window" : {"configure" : {"width" : 500}}})


TasksList = ttk.Notebook(root)
Task1 = tk.Frame(TasksList, bg='white', height = 1000, width = 2000)
text=ScrolledText(Task1, width = 132, height = 120)
text.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
entry1 = Entry(Task1, width = 179)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = W)




Task2 = tk.Frame(TasksList, bg='white')
text=ScrolledText(Task2, width = 132, height = 120)
text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
entry2 = Entry(Task1, width = 179)
entry2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = W)


Task3 = tk.Frame(TasksList, bg = "white")
text=ScrolledText(Task3, width = 132, height = 120)
text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
entry3 = Entry(Task1, width = 179)
entry3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = W)


TasksList.add(Task1,text = 'Click Here In Order To Read The Instructions')
TasksList.add(Task2, text = 'Two Two Two Two Two Two'[0: 40] + '...')
TasksList.add(Task3, text = "Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Extra"[0 : 40] + '...')
TasksList.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+W, columnspan=3)


Photo2 = PhotoImage(file="Add Task Image Button.png")
Button(root, image=Photo2, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)

Photo1= PhotoImage(file="Final Logo.png")


Label(image=Photo1, bg="black", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
```

I have included a lot of code so that it easier to see the organization of the To - Do List. I hope that there is a way to do this, and would appreciate it if someone could help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add menubuttons to a frame and create menus attached to them. See this example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200+800+50')

top = Frame(root, bg='tan')
top.pack(expand='yes', fill='both', padx=20, pady=20)

mb = Menubutton(top, text="condiments", relief=RAISED)
mb.pack(anchor='nw')
mb.menu = Menu(mb, tearoff=0)
mb["menu"] = mb.menu

def hello(): print('Hello')
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="ketchup" )
mb.menu.add_command(label="Hello!", command=hello)

root.mainloop()
```

Adapted from [Python - Tkinter Menubutton](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_menubutton.htm).